# Is it possible to install android market on android sdk

Tags: android

Is it possible to install android market on android sdk?If yes please give me steps.

Comment: Yes I believe you can install Google Play on the Android Emulator. You would have to 'side load' it but it is more hassle than it's worth I'd recommend just getting a real device.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Store (formerly known as the Android Market) is only distributed to device manufacturers who license it. It is not legally available by any other means, and certainly not as a download from random Web sites. Any such site that distributes the Play Store APK is committing and act of software piracy.

If you want the Play Store, buy an Android device.